# Vscode unable to auto indent after enter in bracket - Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want my code to indent after pressing enter inside brackets on javascript

After entering in brackets, my code will look like this:

```
const somefunc = () => {
}
```

I want to look at my code like this:

```
const somefunc = () => {
    //indented
}
```

Comment: Do you mean after pressing enter after `{`?, if so then that works for me.

Comment: yes, It happened after I remove the prettier extension. I think I also tweaked some settings.json code. But I can't find where is the issue after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open setting and change your `editor.autoIndent` to positive

Comment: still doesn't work for me

Comment: try resetting setting completely